# How to start chronometer in reverse in android?

Tags: android

```
cmtr.setText(finalTime);
cmtr.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

timetest = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
Log.d("SETTIME: ", ""+timetest);
cmtr.start();

eltime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
Log.d("ELapsed: ", ""+eltime);
```

Note: i want to start my chronometer in reverse order. like i set chronometer 10 seconds. now, i want to start from 10 to 0 seconds in reverse order. so can anyone help to get this solution.? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can't, the [Chronometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) widget only counts up, that's *the specific purpose it was made for*. If you want to count down, use the [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) (the Android SDK page contains a specific example where a TextView is updated), or roll your own solution.

These classes are trivial wrappers to save you some typing. You really shouldn't feel uncomfortable writing an alternative implementation if they don´t fit your exact needs.

**[Update]**

As Ronaldo Bahia added in the remarks, since API 24 the Chronometer actually offers this functionally through the [setCountDown](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html#setCountDown(boolean)) method.

Comment: me too, this saved me time

Comment: Which is sample using CountDownTimer?

Comment: @Paul-Jan you are right that Chronometer only counts up but a small trick may do it. Please check my answer to this question

Comment: Actually it does perform a countdown: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html#setCountDown(boolean)

Comment: @RonaldoBahia Indeed it does, since API level 24. Which was released 3+ years after this Q&A entry was created, but might be appropriate for use in current applications.

Comment: This should explain how to use setCountDown(), in the context of a complete example. It is counting down from what to what? How would that display?

Answer (score 22):

You can't chronometer widget for counts down. use CountDownTimer example below
here my count down start from 01:45 mins  1sec = 1000

```
 CountDownTimer cT =  new CountDownTimer(100000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


                 String v = String.format("%02d", millisUntilFinished/60000);
                 int va = (int)( (millisUntilFinished%60000)/1000);
                 textView.setText("seconds remaining: " +v+":"+String.format("%02d",va));
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             textView.setText("done!");
         }
      };
      cT.start();
```

Comment: As per you have mentioned its 01:40 mins not 01:45 mins

Answer (score 5):

For those who are still looking for other options and a View, I suggest using the [Chronometer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) widget and setting setCountDown (boolean) to true.

As an example, in your activity or fragment:

```
  view_timer.base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 10000    
  view_timer.start()
```

For the widget in the layout .xml:

```
<Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/view_timer"
            android:countDown="true"
            tools:targetApi="24"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: AFAIK, This should be the new accepted solution.

Answer (score 2):

Also possible to use setCountDown(true);
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html

Comment: Since API level 24 which rules it out for most apps at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Choronometer only counts up. but we can do reverse with this small trick.

```
chrono.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer arg0) {
                countUp = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime) / 1000;

                if (countUp % 2 == 0) {
                    chronoRecordingImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    chronoRecordingImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                int min = (int) (countUp/60);
                int sec = (int) (countUp%60);

                Utility.printMessage(min+":"+sec);
                int newCount = MAX_TIME - (int) countUp;  // MAIN LOGIC
                String asText = String.format("%02d",(newCount / 60)) + ":"
                        + String.format("%02d", (newCount % 60));

                chrono.setText(asText);
                if (countUp > MAX_TIME) {
                    //time complete
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int sec = 60*2;  // this is for 2 for min TODO replace your sec

    public void startTimer(final TextView textView ,int sec) {

    CountDownTimer downTimer= new CountDownTimer(1000 * sec, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


            String v = String.format("%02d", millisUntilFinished / 60000);
            int va = (int) ((millisUntilFinished % 60000) / 1000);
            textView.setText(v + ":" + String.format("%02d", va));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            textView.setText("done!");
        }
    };
    downTimer.start();

}
```

and call this :

```
startTimer(tvClock,sec);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.quanticheart.camera

//
// Created by Jonn Alves on 01/10/22.
//
import android.content.Context
import android.os.CountDownTimer
import android.os.SystemClock
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.Chronometer

class PauseChronometer @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
) : Chronometer(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    private var timeWhenStopped: Long = 0

    override fun start() {
        if (cdMode) {
            if (!cdRunning)
                captureVideoWithDuration(cdSeconds.toInt())
        } else {
            base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - timeWhenStopped
            super.start()
        }
    }

    override fun stop() {
        if (cdMode) {
            cdRunning = false
            cd?.cancel()
        } else {
            super.stop()
            timeWhenStopped = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - base
        }
    }

    fun reset() {
        if (cdMode) {
            cd?.cancel()
            cdSeconds = 0L
            cdMode = false
            cdRunning = false
        } else {
            stop()
            base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
            timeWhenStopped = 0
        }
        text = "00:00"
    }

    private var cd: CountDownTimer? = null
    private var cdSeconds = 0L
    private var cdMode = false
    private var cdRunning = false
    private var cdCallback: (() -> Unit)? = null

    fun startCountdown(seconds: Int) {
        cdSeconds = seconds.toLong()
        cdMode = true
        cd = object : CountDownTimer((seconds * 1000).toLong(), 1000) {
            //Sets 10 second remaining
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                cdRunning = true
                cdSeconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000

                var secondsM = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toInt()

                val hours = secondsM / (60 * 60)
                val tempMint = secondsM - hours * 60 * 60
                val minutes = tempMint / 60
                secondsM = tempMint - minutes * 60

                val t = String.format("%02d", minutes) + ":" + String.format("%02d", secondsM)
                text = t
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                cdCallback?.let { it() }
                cdSeconds = 0
                cdMode = false
                cdRunning = false
            }
        }.start()
    }

    fun setCountDownFinishCallback(callback: () -> Unit) {
        this.cdCallback = callback
    }

    var currentTime: Long
        get() = if (cdMode) cdSeconds else timeWhenStopped
        set(time) {
            if (cdMode)
                cdSeconds = time
            else {
                timeWhenStopped = time
                base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - timeWhenStopped
            }
        }
}
```